# Javascript regex to match a pattern but NOT match a regex literal (r.js optimizer and uglify issue)?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, uglifyjs, r.js

I've got a Backbone application, organized into modules using Require.js. One of these modules contains a Handlebars helper, which has a method I use to pull a legal header off of all our HTML templates for each View. The header is contained in an HTML comment, so I use the following regex to strip it off:

```
/<!--[\s\S]*?-->/g
```

Now, when I optimize (concatenate/compile/minify) the application using r.js, I'm doing the same removal of HTML comments using the `onBuildWrite()` method of r.js:

```
onBuildWrite: function (moduleName, path, contents) {
    var htmlCommentRegex = /<!--[\s\S]*?-->/g;

    return contents.replace(htmlCommentRegex, "");
},
```

Now, unfortunately, this means that when the Require.js module containing the Handlebars helper is pulled into the r.js optimized build, **the regex literal within the helper is stripped out**, causing my entire r.js build to bomb out.

I've tried to resolve the issue by selectively applying the regex in `onBuildWrite()` to all modules EXCEPT the helper:

```
onBuildWrite: function (moduleName, path, contents) {
    var htmlCommentRegex = /<!--[\s\S]*?-->/g;

    if (moduleName !== "helpers/handlebars.compileClean") {
        contents = contents.replace(htmlCommentRegex, "");
    }

    return contents;
},
```

But this doesn't appear to work when uglification is enabled in the r.js configuration; **the regex STILL seems to be running on the entire built script**, including the helper, causing the build to bomb out.

If uglify is disabled in the r.js config, everything works fine.

**Anyone have any ideas why uglify would break this? Would switching to a different regex, that would capture HTML comments but IGNORE the HTML comment regex literal, solve the issue? If so, what would that regex look like?**

Comment: How do you inject your JS to HTML? Maybe your pattern act as HTML comment...

Comment: Inject my JS? Sorry, I'm not following.

Comment: I'm not using backbone and the other stuff but you must load your javascript to html somehow.

Comment: Well, the end result of the r.js optimization is a JS file, not an HTML one, so even if the regex literal were acting as an HTML comment, I wouldn't expect the error to be occurring in the exact location where the regex literal is located in the helper module. I'll take another glance, keeping that in mind, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regexp to:

```
var htmlCommentRegex = /[<]!--[\s\S]*?-->/g;
```

The single-character `[<]` class is equivalent to `<` as far as the RE processor is concerned, but now the RE no longer matches itself.

Another way is to escape one of the literal characters in the RE:

```
var htmlCommentRegex = /<\!--[\s\S]*?-->/g;
```

Or you could build the RE from strings:

```
var htmlCommentRegex = new RegExp('<!'+'--[\s\S]*?-->', 'g');
```

If r.js is optimizing all these back to the original text, try this:

```
var commentPrefix = '<!';
var htmlCommentRegex = new Regexp(commentPrefix+'--[\s\S]*?-->', 'g');
```

Hopefully it doesn't do enough code analysis to undo this obfuscation.

Comment: or just escape it like `/\<!--.*?--\>/g`

Comment: I'll give that a shot, I do recall uglify complaining about unescaped characters. Any idea why uglify would complain about unescaped characters but JS itself has no issue with the regex literal?

Comment: @kbec Only the second escape is needed.

Comment: I'm not familiar with uglify, so no idea. Are you sure it was complaining about the RE, and not something else in the code?

Comment: Well, the errors fluctuate, depending on uglify settings and regex used. Will try your suggestion for sure and report back.

Comment: An update: it appears that r.js is treating the pulled-in modules as text, so when my regex in the build config runs, it's going to pull out the helper regex every time, even if the regex literal in the config is slightly different from the one in the helper, because it still matches the helper's when the helper is treated as text. Using a RegExp constructor didn't solve it, either. I would guess the only solution is going to be a regex that matches HTML comments but DOESN'T match the exact regex literal in the helper.

Comment: I don't see how that can be happening. The whole point of my answer is that the text in the helper does _not_ match the regexp. The regexp matches `<` followed by `!`, but the text has `<` followed by `]`.

Comment: Hmm, I suppose r.js could be optimizing the JS, and realizes that `[<]` can be simplified to `<`. Similary with the string, it performs the concatenation when it's optimizing. I have an idea to try to get around it.

Comment: Yup, looks like your last update did it! So I suppose that means the pulled-in Require.js modules are actually treated as text during the onBuild events, rather than executed as actual JS. Thanks a bunch!