# Using grunt's uglify on handlebars.js gives error

Tags: gruntjs, handlebars.js, minify, uglifyjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I am trying to use uglify on handlebars along with some other files, but the minified file converts this:

```
[^\x00]*?
```

into

```
[^�]*?
```

So IE is having problems parsing this.

I read somewhere that it's a BOM issue. I tried this 
http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.preservebom 
but that did not solve it.
Any solutions?

Comment: I think our solution was to not minify Handlebars ourselves, but to concat the pre-minified version from their site with the other minified files afterward.

Comment: I was trying to avoid that extra step. also I'm using bower so it won't get the minified version

Comment: Hmm... I think you can make bower give you the minified version as well, but on the project I was talking about we weren't using it. Sorry!

Comment: What is the [file encoding](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.defaultencoding)?

Comment: I haven't changed the encoding, but since grunt sets it to UTF by default, I don't think that's the issue

Comment: What version of the uglify task do you use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript regex to match a pattern but NOT match a regex literal (r.js optimizer and uglify issue)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741958/javascript-regex-to-match-a-pattern-but-not-match-a-regex-literal-r-js-optimize)